# Proving Positivity Axiom for Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I am trying to show that
$$
4v_{1}^{2} - 4v_{1}v_{2} + 4v_{2}^{2} \,>\, 0
$$
is true so that I can show that the positivity axiom for inner products holds.  I know I can reduce it to
$$
v_{1}^{2} + v_{2}^{2} \,>\, v_{1}v_{2}
$$
but after that I don't know of a mathematical way to show that it's true.

Thank you in advanced for any help

Comment: Hint: either $v_1 = v_2$, or one is bigger than the other.

Comment: What is about $v_1,v_2$?

Comment: @DavidWheeler That was kind of my thought process. Since $v_{1}^{2} \geq v_{1}$ and $v_{2}^{2} \geq v_{2}$ then $v_{1}^{2} + v_{2}^{2} > v_{1}v_{2}$ but I don't know if that is a mathematically correct statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** note that
$$
4v_{1}^{2} - 4v_{1}v_{2} + 4v_{2}^{2} = \\
3v_1^2 + (v_1^2- 4v_{1}v_{2} + 4v_{2}^{2}) =\\
3v_1^2 + (v_1 - 2v_2)^2
$$
Alternatively, if you've discussed positive definite matrices,
$$
4v_{1}^{2} - 4v_{1}v_{2} + 4v_{2}^{2} = 
\pmatrix{v_1 & v_2} \pmatrix{4&-2\\-2&4} \pmatrix{v_1\\v_2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $v_1^2 - 2v_1v_2 + v_2^2 = (v_1-v_2)^2 \ge 0$ you get $$2v_1 v_2 \le v_1^2 + v_2^2 \le 2 v_1^2 + 2 v_2^2.$$

Comment: That was my first thought, but unfortunately it's $v_{1}^{2} - v_{1}v_{2} + v_{2}^{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a homogeneous quadratic polynomial in two variables, you can de-homogenise it. Setting $t=\dfrac{v_1}{v_2}$, it amounts to checking that $t^2-t+1>0$  for all $t$ — which is true because this polynomial has no real root.